# What is the reason al pi sod for saying migdol in bentching on Chol HaMoed?

Tags: bentching, chol-hamoed

The [Ben Ish Chai Chukas (1:19)](https://www.sefaria.org/Ben_Ish_Hai%2C_Halachot_1st_Year%2C_Chukat.19.1?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) writes

> בארבע סעודות שבת וכן ביום טוב וחול המועד וראש חודש אומרים מגדול בו"ו,
> וכתב בחסד לאלפים בשם הרב רבי דוד פאדרו ז"ל שגם בסעודת מילה ראוי לומר
> מגדול בוא"ו על פי הסוד יעוין שם
>
> During the four meals on Shabbos, and on Yom Tov, Chol HaMoed, and Rosh Chodesh we say Migdol with a vav on Rosh Chodesh, as well as at the meal of a bris milah it's fitting to say Migdol, for a kabbalistic reason.

Why do we specifically say Migdol on Chol HaMoed?

Comment: Chol HaMoed seems to me to fit right in with the other examples in your source. What is confusing about its inclusion that you ask about it specifically?

Comment: Musaf.............